# Vue.js router multiple redirects in address bar

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I just built a project using Vue.js. It all runs great but there's a problem.
When I connect a user to the app, he is redirected to `/`, and the title becomes `http://localhost:8080/#/?redirect=%2Flogin`, which is ok I guess.

If I now logout (which moves the user to `/login`, the address bar is:
`http://localhost:8080/#/login?redirect=%2F%3Fredirect%3D%252Flogin`

This is my `router.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import Login from './views/Login.vue'
import Register from './views/Register.vue'
import firebase from 'firebase'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/about',
      name: 'about',
      // route level code-splitting
      // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
      // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ './views/About.vue')
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'login',
      component: Login,
      meta: {
        requiresGuest: true
      }
    },
    {
      path: '/register',
      name: 'register',
      component: Register,
      meta: {
        requiresGuest: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (!user) {
        next({
          path: '/login',
          query: {
            redirect: to.fullPath
          }
        })
      } else {
          next();
      }
      });
  }
  else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresGuest)) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        next({
          path: '/',
          query: {
            redirect: to.fullPath
          }
        })
      } else {
          next();
      }
      });
  }
  else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is your desired result?

Comment: @Jeff multiple redirects in the URL doesn't seem correct.